# Exporting an existing leaflet map as KML/KMZ format in R

Tags: r, leaflet, kml

I have written a script in R to draw a dynamic map that users can interact with using the leaflet package. I need to submit this map as a KML/KMZ format for it to be acceptable according to the journal's requirements.

Is there an function in R that I can save the map as one of these format so that it can be compatible with google earth?

Comment: Try with `raster::KML()`